# can't delete google cloud project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

```
gcloud projects delete test-henx
```

When I try to delete `test-henx` project, error occurs like this.

```
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

ERROR: (gcloud.projects.delete) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Precondition check failed.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - description: 'A lien to prevent deletion was placed on the project by [You cannot
      delete this project because it is linked with a Dialogflow agent. Please follow
      the link to Dialogflow and delete the agent: https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/#/agent/07872f08-081d-4724-bd2e-b218061fbc5a].
      Remove the lien to allow deletion.'
    subject: liens/p417959660558-lcc0da1eb-7f47-4fb3-81a1-bcbf35011fad
    type: LIEN
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help
  links:
  - description: Troubleshooting project deletion
    url: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/troubleshooting-project-deletion
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
  reason: PROJECT_DELETE_LIEN
```

If I click the link `https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/#/agent/07872f08-081d-4724-bd2e-b218061fbc5a].`, there is no agent and also this error: `IAM permission 'dialogflow.agents.get' on 'projects/07872f08-081d-4724-bd2e-b218061fbc5a].' denied.` shows up.

Removing lien using gcloud shell also doesn't work.

```
gcloud endpoints services delete 07872f08-081d-4724-bd2e-b218061fbc5a]
Are you sure? This will set the service configuration to be deleted, along with all of the associated consumer information. Note: This does not immediately delete the service configuration or data and can be undone using the undelete command
 for 30 days. Only after 30 days will the service be purged from the system.

Continue anyway (Y/n)?  Y

ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.delete) User [wkdgusrhkd@gmail.com] does not have permission to access services instance [07872f08-081d-4724-bd2e-b218061fbc5a%5D] (or it may not exist): Service '07872f08-081d-4724-bd2e-b218061fbc5a]' not found or permission denied.

wkdgusrhkd@cloudshell:~ (test-henx)$ gcloud endpoints services delete 07872f08-081d-4724-bd2e-b218061fbc5a
Are you sure? This will set the service configuration to be deleted, along with all of the associated consumer information. Note: This does not immediately delete the service configuration or data and can be undone using the undelete command
 for 30 days. Only after 30 days will the service be purged from the system.

Continue anyway (Y/n)?  Y

ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.delete) User [wkdgusrhkd@gmail.com] does not have permission to access services instance [07872f08-081d-4724-bd2e-b218061fbc5a] (or it may not exist): Service '07872f08-081d-4724-bd2e-b218061fbc5a' not found or permission denied.
```

Comment: List and delete this way https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-liens#listing_liens_on_a_project

Comment: Ok then ill put it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List this way: `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list`

And to delete please use this command as an example:

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete [LIEN_NAME]
```

Comment: This was very useful. Thanks a lot. I was struggling to delete my project since a long and was being charged, even though I hadn't been using it